# How to set the second y-axis in ggplot without rescaling?

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

This is my dataframe:

```
df = dput(sent_results)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(11688, 11719, 11747, 11778, 
11808, 11839, 11869, 11931, 11961, 11992, 12022, 12053, 12084, 
12112, 12143, 12173, 12204, 12234, 12296, 12326, 12357, 12387, 
12418, 12449, 12478, 12509, 12539, 12570, 12600, 12662, 12692, 
12723, 12753, 12784, 12815, 12843, 12874, 12904, 12935, 12965, 
13027, 13057, 13088, 13118, 13149, 13180, 13208, 13239, 13269, 
13300, 13330, 13361, 13361, 13422, 13453, 13483, 13514, 13545, 
13573, 13604, 13634, 13665, 13695, 13757, 13787, 13818, 13848, 
13879, 13910, 13939, 13970, 14000, 14031, 14061, 14092, 14123, 
14153, 14184, 14214, 14245, 14276, 14304, 14335, 14365, 14396, 
14426, 14457, 14488, 14518, 14549, 14579, 14610, 14641, 14669, 
14700, 14730, 14761, 14791, 14822, 14853, 14883, 14914, 14944, 
14975, 15006, 15034, 15065, 15095, 15126, 15156, 15187, 15218, 
15248, 15279, 15309, 15340, 15371, 15400, 15431, 15461, 15492, 
15522, 15553, 15584, 15614, 15645, 15675, 15706, 15737, 15765, 
15796, 15826, 15857, 15887, 15918, 15949, 15979, 16010, 16040, 
16071, 16102, 16130, 16161, 16191, 16222, 16252, 16283, 16314, 
16344, 16375, 16405, 16436, 16495, 16526, 16587, 16617, 16679, 
16709, 16770, 16801, 16861, 16892, 16953, 16983, 17045, 17075, 
17136, 17167, 17226, 17257, 17318, 17348, 17410, 17440, 17501, 
17532, 17591, 17622, 17683, 17713, 17775, 17805, 17866, 17897, 
17956, 17987, 18048, 18078, 18140, 18170, 18231, 18262, 18322, 
18353, 18414, 18444), class = "Date"), IP = c(-0.595925341785417, 
-0.566320864529598, -0.487375591847412, -0.507111910017959, -0.467639273676865, 
-0.418298478250498, -0.497243750932684, -0.428166637335771, -0.487375591847412, 
-0.428166637335771, -0.566320864529598, -0.418298478250498, -0.398562160079952, 
-0.477507432762138, -0.438034796421045, -0.595925341785417, -0.595925341785417, 
-0.438034796421045, -0.566320864529598, -0.329485046483038, -0.359089523738859, 
-0.329485046483038, -0.349221364653585, -0.309748728312493, -0.329485046483038, 
-0.250539773800852, -0.230803455630306, -0.230803455630306, -0.15185818294812, 
-0.21106713745976, -0.161726342033394, -0.270276091971399, -0.270276091971399, 
-0.191330819289213, -0.21106713745976, -0.220935296545033, -0.0827810693512062, 
-0.21106713745976, -0.1222537056923, -0.0729129102659335, -0.043308433010114, 
-0.0334402739248399, 0.134318430524805, 0.0257686805867993, 0.104713953268985, 
0.104713953268985, 0.173791066865899, 0.203395544121718, 0.351417930400817, 
0.341549771315545, 0.321813453144998, 0.351417930400817, 0.351417930400817, 
0.33168161223027, 0.430363203083003, 0.578385589362102, 0.53891295302101, 
0.598121907532649, 0.647462702959016, 0.519176634850464, 0.706671657470656, 
0.706671657470656, 0.726407975641202, 0.746144293811749, 0.834957725579209, 
0.765880611982296, 0.825089566493935, 0.913902998261395, 0.894166680090848, 
0.854694043749756, 0.973111952773034, 0.65733086204429, 0.677067180214835, 
0.56851743027683, 0.529044793935736, 0.45009952125355, 0.183659225951171, 
-0.181462660203939, -0.516980069103231, -0.90183827342889, -1.10906961421963, 
-1.21761936415763, -1.33603727318091, -1.13867409147545, -1.07946513696381, 
-1.06959697787853, -1.06959697787853, -0.852497478002523, -0.891970114343616, 
-0.862365637087796, -0.852497478002523, -0.704475091723424, -0.753815887149791, 
-0.586057182700145, -0.536716387273778, -0.368957682824132, -0.359089523738859, 
-0.398562160079952, -0.319616887397766, -0.299880569227219, -0.220935296545033, 
-0.132121864777573, -0.0531765920953867, -0.102517387521753, 
-0.0137039557542944, 0.00603236241625246, -0.043308433010114, 
0.0159005215015266, -0.1222537056923, -0.0235721148395671, -0.0137039557542944, 
-0.112385546607027, -0.141990023862847, -0.112385546607027, -0.171594501118666, 
-0.24067161471558, -0.181462660203939, -0.191330819289213, -0.270276091971399, 
-0.201198978374486, -0.280144251056672, -0.250539773800852, -0.181462660203939, 
-0.368957682824132, -0.438034796421045, -0.507111910017959, -0.457771114591592, 
-0.497243750932684, -0.477507432762138, -0.378825841909405, -0.359089523738859, 
-0.339353205568312, -0.339353205568312, -0.418298478250498, -0.368957682824132, 
-0.359089523738859, -0.408430319165226, -0.280144251056672, -0.299880569227219, 
-0.329485046483038, -0.260407932886127, -0.309748728312493, -0.161726342033394, 
-0.24067161471558, -0.290012410141946, -0.21106713745976, -0.378825841909405, 
-0.280144251056672, -0.309748728312493, -0.339353205568312, -0.21106713745976, 
-0.230803455630306, 0.0455049987573461, -0.043308433010114, 0.00603236241625246, 
0.065241316927893, -0.00383579666902026, 0.0159005215015266, 
-0.0334402739248399, 0.262604498633359, 0.0257686805867993, 0.134318430524805, 
0.0751094760131657, 0.0849776350984384, 0.114582112354259, 0.233000021377538, 
0.213263703206992, 0.193527385036445, 0.242868180462812, 0.33168161223027, 
0.311945294059725, 0.47970399850937, 0.489572157594644, 0.47970399850937, 
0.765880611982296, 0.558649271191557, 0.489572157594644, 0.489572157594644, 
0.578385589362102, 0.469835839424097, 0.509308475765191, 0.519176634850464, 
0.410626884912458, 0.489572157594644, 0.459967680338824, 0.410626884912458, 
0.351417930400817, 0.341549771315545, 0.341549771315545, 0.302077134974451, 
0.0948457941837126, 0.282340816803904, -0.911706432514163, -2.53995268158425, 
-0.832761159831976, -0.378825841909405), Sentiment = c(0.010752688172043, 
0.0625, 0.0634920634920635, 0.0467289719626168, 0.0761904761904762, 
0.0747663551401869, 0.0759493670886076, 0.0306748466257669, -0.025, 
0.0136986301369863, -0.021978021978022, -0.0645161290322581, 
-0.00746268656716418, 0.0172413793103448, -0.0857142857142857, 
-0.0229007633587786, 0.0111111111111111, -0.00892857142857143, 
0.0126582278481013, 0.0144927536231884, 0.112, 0.0775862068965517, 
0.065359477124183, 0.0786516853932584, 0.032967032967033, 0.0378151260504202, 
0.0535714285714286, 0.101694915254237, 0.0967741935483871, 0.0892857142857143, 
0.115044247787611, 0.130434782608696, 0.111764705882353, 0.0754716981132075, 
0.176470588235294, 0.043859649122807, 0.173076923076923, 0.105263157894737, 
0.0441767068273092, 0.0833333333333333, 0.125, 0.114285714285714, 
0.0288461538461538, 0.0327868852459016, 0.0857142857142857, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0641025641025641, 0.142857142857143, 0.127118644067797, 0.080168776371308, 
0.135922330097087, 0.0473684210526316, 0.0772200772200772, 0.0646551724137931, 
0.0454545454545455, 0.0485436893203883, 0.0909090909090909, 0.0661764705882353, 
0.0689655172413793, 0.147286821705426, 0.16, 0.0810810810810811, 
0.0880503144654088, 0.0337552742616034, 0.0656934306569343, -0.0050251256281407, 
0.0173913043478261, 0, -0.0114942528735632, 0.00411522633744856, 
0.0168539325842697, -0.0178571428571429, 0.00727272727272727, 
-0.0201612903225806, -0.0588235294117647, -0.0463917525773196, 
-0.12037037037037, -0.0782608695652174, -0.0920502092050209, 
-0.0963855421686747, -0.0897435897435897, -0.0566801619433198, 
-0.0769230769230769, -0.0925925925925926, -0.0463320463320463, 
-0.0403225806451613, -0.0625, -0.0194552529182879, -0.0314465408805031, 
-0.00636942675159236, 0.014218009478673, -0.00602409638554217, 
-0.0132450331125828, -0.0158730158730159, -0.0261780104712042, 
-0.0284090909090909, -0.0112781954887218, -0.0363636363636364, 
-0.0130718954248366, 0.0197628458498024, -0.0206896551724138, 
-0.03125, 0.00434782608695652, -0.0194805194805195, -0.012987012987013, 
-0.0048780487804878, -0.0229885057471264, -0.0166666666666667, 
0.0132013201320132, 0.0122699386503067, 0, -0.0137614678899083, 
-0.0458015267175573, -0.0563380281690141, -0.056, -0.0531914893617021, 
-0.0540540540540541, -0.037037037037037, -0.0540540540540541, 
-0.0427350427350427, -0.00666666666666667, -0.0373831775700935, 
-0.0526315789473684, -0.0142857142857143, -0.0512820512820513, 
-0.0381679389312977, -0.0344827586206897, -0.0578512396694215, 
-0.0542635658914729, -0.0416666666666667, -0.0666666666666667, 
-0.0551181102362205, -0.0338164251207729, -0.0463576158940397, 
-0.0466666666666667, -0.00836820083682008, -0.0164835164835165, 
0, 0.00947867298578199, 0, 0, -0.00425531914893617, 0, -0.0198675496688742, 
-0.0214592274678112, -0.0062111801242236, -0.0112359550561798, 
-0.0507246376811594, -0.0133333333333333, -0.0198675496688742, 
-0.0268199233716475, 0.0652173913043478, 0.0404040404040404, 
0.0545454545454545, 0.0470588235294118, 0.0373831775700935, -0.00934579439252336, 
0.0133333333333333, 0.0392156862745098, -0.00645161290322581, 
0, 0.0133333333333333, 0.013953488372093, 0.049645390070922, 
0.0151515151515152, 0.0396825396825397, 0.0658682634730539, 0.0932203389830508, 
0.0638297872340425, 0.0859375, 0.0495049504950495, 0.0930232558139535, 
0.0867052023121387, 0.11864406779661, 0.10989010989011, 0.134453781512605, 
0.102857142857143, 0.126865671641791, 0.0609137055837563, 0.0604026845637584, 
0.0823529411764706, 0.0526315789473684, 0.0212765957446809, -0.0212765957446809, 
0.0125, 0.0148514851485149, 0.0241545893719807, 0.0101010101010101, 
0.0177514792899408, 0.0446428571428571, 0.0227272727272727, 0.0508474576271186, 
-0.0699300699300699, -0.0866425992779783, -0.0557103064066852, 
-0.0384615384615385)), row.names = c(NA, -196L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to plot two lines in ggplot and change the second y-axis. Unlike many solutions, I have not resclaed the second y-axis so I just need to type "numbers" on the second axis. I attempted this unsuccessful solution:

```
# Vector of desired breakpoints for secondary axis
sec_breaks <- c(75, 85, 95, 105, 110)
# Vector of breakpoints for the first axis
scaled_breaks <- c(-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1)

g = ggplot(df) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=Date, y=Sentiment*10), color= "#4C74C9", size=1) +
  geom_line(aes(x=Date, y=IP), color= "red4", linetype = "dashed", size=1) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill=NA)) + labs(y="% \n", x = "") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(75, 85, 95, 105, 110),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~.,
                                         breaks = scaled_breaks,
                                         labels = sprintf("%.3f", sec_breaks))) 
g = g + geom_rect(data=recessions.df, aes(xmin=Peak, xmax=Trough, ymin=-Inf, ymax=+Inf), fill='grey', alpha=0.2)
g
```

I got what you see below:
[image]

Instead, I would like to have both y-axes with numbers and spaced properly.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to compute the scaling factor so that you can manage the axis!

Comment: there is not a way just to write on the second y axis without rescaling?

Comment: yes, you can do it (even if quite unnecessarily complicated). But I dont understand what your expected result should be.

Comment: on the first axis: `c(-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1)` and on the second axis: `c(75, 85, 95, 105, 110)`

Comment: also your code is quite dirty: you have two `scale_y_continuous` and the first one looks like it has nothing to do with your graph (it also gets ignored)

Comment: You want to see those numbers.. but where? You don't want to scale your data directly, you just want them to appear to be scaled because you change the values on the axis, right? However, you need to specify what kind of rescaling you have in mind on the axis.

Comment: Try to create a chart with rescaled data. From there I can create a chart with rescaled axis but without actually rescaling your data.

Comment: ok so  I guess it's just easier to scale it and get what I need rather than finding a cumbersome way to to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can transform your axis without changing your data:

```
library(ggplot2)

correction_factor <- 10
pretty_breaks1 <- pretty(c(df$Sentiment, df$IP / correction_factor))
pretty_breaks2 <- pretty_breaks1 * correction_factor
scaled_labels1 <- pretty_breaks1  * 10       # make the tranformation you want to have 
scaled_labels2 <- pretty_breaks2  * 10 + 95  # make the tranformation you want to have


ggplot(df, aes(x = Date)) + 
   geom_line(aes(y = Sentiment), color= "#4C74C9", size=1) +
   geom_line(aes(y = IP / correction_factor), color= "red4", linetype = "dashed", size=1) +
   theme_classic() +
   theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill=NA)) +
   labs(y="%", x = "") +
   scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks1,
                      labels = scaled_labels1,
                      sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~.*correction_factor,
                                          breaks = pretty_breaks2,
                                          labels = scaled_labels2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was just editing the code to make your life easier but then you got faster. Thanks again! super helpful!